# Rounding error when casting from float to double and back

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding

To comply with the interface of a library I have to round a float to a double, and then back to float again, without any additional manipulation in between. I'd need to understand if the final value is guaranteed to be equal (in the sense of `==`) to the original float value, or if there are cases when this is a safe assumptions.

Comment: "Round a float to a double": why? Why not just assign it?

Comment: @user207421: I simplified the description of the problem, the real one is more involved but details are not essential. Anyway, nothing is actually cast but there are just an assignment from float to double and another from double to float.

Comment: So nothing is explicitly rounded. So why did you use the term `round`? Please clarify your question.

Comment: With IEEE754 floating-point representation, all single precision floating point values are exactly representable in double-precision. Relevant questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14773142/580083, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5777484/580083. C++ standard quote: [The set of values of the type `float` is a subset of the set of values of the type `double`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#12.sentence-3).

Comment: Of course, "equal in the sense of `==`" is not true for NaNs (regardless of any intermediate conversions).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you mean by "rouding" float to double. But if you mean *conversion*, then, IMO, the value is guaranteed to be preserved.

Relevant parts of the C++ standard:

> The set of values of the type `float` is a **subset of the set of values of the type `double`**;...

http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#12.sentence-3

> A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of another floating-point type. If the **source value can be exactly represented in the destination type**, the result of the conversion **is that exact representation**.

http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.double#1.sentence-2